# Ignore vertical spaces that follow one another

Tags: spacing, vertical

In the code above I have poorly automated some vertical spaces as you can see in the following output. I would like that in my code `\spaceafter \spacebefore` becomes `\spacebefore`. What is the good way to deal with such situation ?

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

    \newcommand\blabla{
        Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla,
        bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla,
        bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla
    }

    \newcommand\spacebefore{\par \bigskip \par}
    \newcommand\spaceafter{\par \medskip \par}

    \newcommand\specialtext[1]{
        \spacebefore
        #1
        \spaceafter
    }

\begin{document}

\specialtext{SOME TEXT}

\blabla{}

\specialtext{Other text}

\blabla{}


\specialtext{SOME TEXT}

\specialtext{Other text}

\blabla{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\spacebefore}{\par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}}`

Comment: Thanks for your proposition but this not works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\addvspace`. Two consecutive `\addvspace` commands make for a vertical spacing the size of the maximum of the two.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\blabla{%
  Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla,
  bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla,
  bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla%
}

\newcommand\spacebefore{\par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}}
\newcommand\spaceafter{\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\newcommand\specialtext[1]{%
  \spacebefore
  #1
  \spaceafter
}

\begin{document}

\blabla

\specialtext{SOME TEXT}

\blabla

\specialtext{Other text}

\blabla

\specialtext{SOME TEXT}

\specialtext{Other text}

\blabla

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change `\bigskipamount` with `2cm` and `\medskipamount` with `0.5cm`, I get

[image]

which shows more clearly that the spacing are exactly what you claim you'd like to get.